# ArrayPlot with cells labeled by corresponding values

Tags: plotting

I would like to have `ArrayPlot[]` also present the value of each cell in it, similar to the `LabelingFunction` that is available in other types of plots. How do I do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this?

```
SeedRandom[42, Method -> "Legacy"]; (* for reproducibility *)

mat = RandomReal[1, {3, 5}];
ArrayPlot[mat, 
          Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, Reverse[mat], {2}]}, 
          Mesh -> True]
```

[image: labeled ArrayPlot[]]

Comment: +1, answers the question. How about a contrasting text color (black on white, white on black,..)? I won't be able to upvote a second time for it, though :-)

Comment: @stevenvh I guess something like `Round[1 - GrayLevel[...]]` should do it

Comment: That was my first idea as well, but at 50 % gray you won't see anything :-(

Comment: yes thanks this is great

Comment: @steven, [$\gamma$-tweaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) might do the trick in that case; I'll play around and edit this answer if I see something I like.

Comment: @stevenvh That's why the `Round` is there to make it 0/1 (I see I goofed the syntax). This doesn't look so bad, I think: `Graphics[{{GrayLevel[#], Disk[]}, {GrayLevel[Round[1 - #]], 
      Text[Style["Disk", FontSize -> 16]]}}] & /@ 
  Range[0, 1, 0.1] // Row`. Of course, there are better methods as J. M. suggests :)

Comment: In my opinion you get better readability for the intermediate gray levels with `GrayLevel[Round[1.2 - #]]` instead of `GrayLevel[Round[1 - #]]`. Might also depend on the monitor settings.

Comment: mat = {{17, 18, 100}, {2, 4, a}, {0, 0, 3}}
ArrayPlot[mat, 
 Epilog -> {MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, 
    Reverse[mat], {2}]}, Mesh -> True]

Comment: Guys hi. So here is the next obsacle of this problem: for some reason this works: mat = {{17, 18, 100}, {2, 4, a}, {0, 0, 3}}
ArrayPlot[mat, 
 Epilog -> {MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, 
    Reverse[mat], {2}]}, Mesh -> True] But when trying to put Manipulate into it this one does not: Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[mat[a],  
  Epilog -> {MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 0.5]] &, 
     Reverse[dat], {2}]}, Mesh -> True], {a, 0, 4}] is there any clue to what i am doing wrong her?