# How to correctly map values onto an arrayplot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to understand why the order of the text is reversed from what it should be? If I compare the first and second results, I see that the {1,1}, {2,2},... diagonal is going down the wrong diagonal. How could I alter this, such that the order is correct? 
For reference, here is the original question...[ArrayPlot with cells labeled by corresponding values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/arrayplot-with-cells-labeled-by-corresponding-values)

```
SeedRandom[41, Method -> "Legacy"];(*for reproducibility*)  
mat = RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]  
ArrayPlot[  
 mat,  
 Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[
   Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, mat, {2}]},  
 Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 400]  

mat = RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]  
ArrayPlot[  
 mat,  
 Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[
   Text[#2, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, mat, {2}]},  
 Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Pickett code has been updated, had a rogue Style command that I removed. Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to include the `Reverse`. Reread J.M.'s answer, he uses `Reverse[mat]`.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus yes, you are correct. Thanks for the extra set of eyes. Lol, I feel sheepish now!

Comment: @tarhawk: It still doesn't fix your second example, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus, yeah I'm not sure whats going on there? It looks like I'll spend a good bit of time troubleshooting. There's an additional problem if the values are less than zero, as the colorfunctionscaling is incorrect. That problem's been addressed, but it is still a bit of a head scratcher. `SeedRandom[41, Method -> "Legacy"]; RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}]
ArrayPlot[mat, Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, mat, {2}]}, Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 400]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[41, Method -> "Legacy"];

(mat = RandomReal[1, {4, 4}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
 ArrayPlot[
     mat,
     Epilog -> 
      MapIndexed[Text[Framed[#1, Background -> White], #2 - 1/2] &,
        Transpose@Reverse@mat, {2}],
     Mesh -> True,
     PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
     ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**Update**

To handle negative values you must specify a "matching" `PlotRange`

```
SeedRandom[41, Method -> "Legacy"];
mat = Round[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}], 0.01];

ArrayPlot[
 mat,
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit",
 Epilog -> 
  MapIndexed[Text[Framed[#1, Background -> White], #2 - 1/2] &,
   Transpose@Reverse@mat, {2}],
 Mesh -> True,
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that you the first argument of `ArrayPlot` should be `mat` as your values do not correspond to correct shades

Comment: @ubpdqn Thank you very much - updated :)

Comment: @eldo The additional transpose also did the trick for the ordering.