# Adjusting components of the MatrixPlot

Tags: graphics, plotting

I have the following code which yields the figure attached:

```
MatrixPlot[{{1, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 7}}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.019]], 
   FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[left], 
    HoldForm[right]}, {HoldForm[bottom], HoldForm[top]}}, 
   PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Matrix*Plot], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Aharoni", 24, GrayLevel[0], Bold}]
```

How do I perform the following:

1) Increase the spacing between the words "`Matrix Plot`" and "`top`"

2) Label each pixel as `"(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)..."` etc

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you chose not to use strings: `MatrixPlot[{{1, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 7}}, FrameLabel -> {{"Left", "Right"}, {"Bottom", "Top"}}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.019]], PlotLabel -> Style["Matrix Plot\n", Blue]]`.

Comment: I should have used strings, thanks. The use of Style["Matrix Plot\n",Blue] fixes the first part...increases distance between the two words. How about inserting labels at centre of each pixel?

Comment: You shoul be able to adapt [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9885) to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions provided by J.M, I have employed the following code to get the desired output. So credit rightly belong to J.M

```
 MatrixPlot[{{1, 4, 8}, {2, 5, 7}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Bottom", "Top"}, {"Left", "Right"}}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.019]], 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Aharoni", 30, GrayLevel[0], Bold}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Matrix Plot\n", Red],  
 Epilog -> {Blue, 
   MapIndexed[
    Text[Style[#1, Red, Bold, Italic, 22], Reverse[#2 - 1/2], 
      Background -> Yellow] & , 
         Reverse[
     Array[StringForm["(`1`,`2`)", ##1] & , {2, 3}]], {2}]}, 
   Mesh -> True]
```

Have incorporated later suggestions in this edited version

[image]

Comment: You can use `Style[]` within `Text[]` for changing colors and font sizes. As for labels, try this: ``MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, Blue], Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, 
 Reverse[Array[StringForm["(`1`,`2`)", ##] &, {2, 3}]], {2}]``