# Nice presentation of correlation matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, data

IO have those data as a text file

```
tmp = {
{"Canada", 57.9, 14.5, 25.7, 2., 0.966},
{"USA", 6.3, 19.1, 71.7, 2.4, 0.956},
{"Mexique", 10.6, 3.8, 81.7, 4., 0.854},
{"Bresil", 83.9, 2.8, 9.3, 4., 0.813},
{"Allemagne", 4.3, 21.9, 62.3, 10.8, 0.947},
{"Belgique", 1.9, 54.4, 40.2, 2.7, 0.953},
{"Espagne", 9.9, 17.8, 61.7, 10., 0.955},
{"Finlande", 17.4, 28.8, 40.6, 12.9, 0.959},
{"France", 11.2, 77., 9.9, 1.5, 0.961},
{"Pays-Bas", 0.1, 4.3, 86.9, 7.2, 0.964},
{"Royaume-Uni", 2.3, 15.6, 76.8, 4.1, 0.947},
{"Suede", 44.7, 44.7, 3.9, 6.1, 0.963},
{"Suisse", 53.9, 41., 1.5, 1.7, 0.96},
{"Tchequie", 2.9, 29.6, 66.5, 1., 0.903},
{"Hongrie", 0.5, 36.7, 54.3, 8.1, 0.879},
{"Russie", 18.7, 15.9, 65., 0., 0.817},
{"Ukraine", 6.4, 48.1, 45.5, 0.1, 0.796},
{"Afrique.du.Sud", 2.3, 4.3, 93.3, 0.1, 0.683},
{"Chine", 14.2, 2., 83.5, 0.3, 0.772},
{"Japon", 7.5, 24.2, 65.6, 2.2, 0.96},
{"Inde", 15.2, 2.6, 80.4, 1.8, 0.612},
{"Nouvelle-Zelande", 54.4, 0., 34.2, 11.5, 0.95}
}
```

And I `Import`ed it as a text file with option "data".

Then I can select only the data by

```
 tmp1 = Rest[tmp[[All, 2 ;; 6]]]
```

Then I can calculate the matrix of correlations

```
 Correlation[tmp1]
```

No problem and easy done. But I want to make a nice presentation of the correlation coefficient in a grid or a table with the name of the 
items as entry in line and column and positive correlation in blue - or the background of its cell in LightBlue and in LightRed the negative correlations.

At the end, I would like to conduct an acp and make presentation as in R. One can find [an example here](http://www.univ-orleans.fr/mapmo/membres/berglund/exemples_acp.pdf).

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you want `Correlation[tmp1]`? Or do you actually want `Correlation[Transpose[tmp1]]`, giving the correlation between countries?

Answer (score 10):

For `corr = Correlation[tmp1];`:

```
ticks = {{Table[{i, "row " <> ToString[i]}, {i, 1, Length@corr}], None}, 
{None, Table[{i, "column " <> ToString[i]}, {i, 1, Length@corr}]}};

matplot1 = 
 MatrixPlot[corr, 
  Epilog -> {Black, 
    MapIndexed[Text[#1, Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, Reverse[corr], {2}]}, 
  Mesh -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Temperature", "Reverse"}], 
  FrameTicks -> ticks]
```

[image]

I took the `Epilog` for placing the values in respective cells from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/arrayplot-with-cells-labeled-by-corresponding-values/9885#9885).

---

If you want the correlation between countries:

```
names = tmp[[All, 1]];

corr1 = Correlation[Transpose@tmp1];

ticks = {{Table[{i, names[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length@corr1}], None}, 
{None, Table[{i, Rotate[names[[i]], 90 Degree]}, {i, 1, Length@corr1}]}};

matplot2 = 
 MatrixPlot[corr1, Mesh -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Temperature", "Reverse"}], 
  FrameTicks -> ticks]
```

[image]

I rotated the ticks of the columns to be better visible, and removed the `Epilog` as it was unreadable.

Comment: Hello, may you tell me how to make the plot legend the same hight as the main matrixplot?