# Correct format and options of MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting, matrix

Why is that my plot is returning an error? My `sect[[]]` returns a correct format for the range parameter of the plot. But still only getting one color in the full matrix graphic. Is there another way to set the parameters?

```
g[x_, y_] = 10 Cosh[(4 x/2 + .5)*Pi] Sinh[(4 y/2 + 1.1)*Pi]
sect = {{x, 0, 5 Pi}, {y, 0, 5 Pi}}
sect[[1]]
sect[[2]]
r = MatrixPlot[Table[g[x, y], sect[[1]], sect[[2]]], 
  ImageSize -> {700, 700}, AspectRatio -> Full]
```

The resulting image is picking up just one color and not a profile from `0` to `5 Pi`.

Getting this error :  But I see that Set returns the correct format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g[x_, y_] := 10 Cosh[(4 x/2 + .5)*Pi] Sinh[(4 y/2 + 1.1)*Pi]
sect = {{x, 0, 5 Pi}, {y, 0, 5 Pi}};
ticks = Table[{i, i 5 Pi/16}, {i, 2, 16, 2}];
(*OR:  ticks = Transpose @ {Range[0,16,2],Subdivide[5 Pi,8]}; *)

r = MatrixPlot[Table[g[x, y], Evaluate@sect[[1]], Evaluate@sect[[2]]],
     FrameTicks -> {{ticks, ticks}, {ticks, ticks}}, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

---

The picture is clearer with a log-scale:

```
r = MatrixPlot[
     Table[Log @ g[x, y], Evaluate@sect[[1]], Evaluate@sect[[2]]], 
      FrameTicks -> {{ticks, ticks}, {ticks, ticks}}, 
       PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

(See also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126109/nice-presentation-of-correlation-matrix/126114#126114)).