# Adding a number to each cell in a MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
A = RandomInteger[1, {5, 5}];
MatrixPlot[A, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black, Frame -> None]
```

Which produces:

[image]

Now, I'd like to add the numbers 1 through 25 to the center of each cell. Across the first row: 1,2,3,4,5. Second row: 6,7,8,9,10. Third row: 11,12,13,14,15. Fourth row: 16,17,18,19,20. Fifth row: 21,22,23,24,25.

Does anyone have a nice suggestion as to how I can do this?

A second question. My matrix is filled with 0's and 1's. How can I assign the color yellow to 0 and the color blue to 1?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a simple function `ColorRules` for that. In this specific instance, the text most easily gotten with a `Table[]` of `Graphics[Text[]]`.

```
A = RandomInteger[1, {5, 5}];
MatrixPlot[A, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black, Frame -> None, 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Yellow, 1 -> Blue}, 
 Epilog -> {Table[
    Text[i + 5 (j - 1), {i - 0.5, 5.5 - j}], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Might be better to use `Epilog -> Table[Text[...],...]` for the labels instead of `Show`.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Arguably yes.

Comment: @Feyre Thanks for the wonderful help.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ColorFunction` and `MapIndexed` (building on [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126114/22013)):

```
A = RandomInteger[1, {5, 5}];

MatrixPlot[A, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Black, Frame -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (If[# == 1, Blue, Yellow] &), 
 Epilog -> {Black, 
   MapIndexed[Text[#1, #2 - 1/2]&, 
    Transpose@Reverse@Partition[Range@25, 5], {2}]}]
```

[image]

In `MapIndexed`, the function `Text[#1, #2 - 1/2]&` makes automatic placements of the text; I wanted to use simply `Range@25` hence the `Transpose@Reverse`.

Comment: This was also wonderful help and I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the  MapIndexed[Text[#1, #2 - 1/2]&, 
    Transpose@Reverse@Partition[Range@25, 5], {2}] command, but I did learn a lot. Thanks.