# Changing font size when using Epilog on ArrayPlot

Tags: plotting

Following up on the question [ArrayPlot with cells labeled by corresponding values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/arrayplot-with-cells-labeled-by-corresponding-values?newreg=94168e7f0f4e43cb9c5944a776fffc4f): how do I change the font size of the `Epilog` overlay?

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
Epilog -> {Red, MapIndexed[Text[Style[Round[#1, .0001], 16], Reverse[#2 - 1/2]] &, 
   Reverse[mat], {2}]}
```

gives

[image]